# Android: Efficient reading of SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, synchronized

The following code runs on the GUI-Thread (which is the only thread).

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int n1 = prefs.getInt("num1", -1);
int n2 = prefs.getInt("num2", -1);
...
int n10 = prefs.getInt("num10", -1);
```

Each of the `prefs.getInt()` is synchronized (in `SharedPreferencesImpl`), which could slow down the execution.

Will the code run faster if the whole `HashMap` is read from disk at once, and the individual values are retrieved from the local copy?

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
HashMap<String, Object> prefCopy = (HashMap<String, Object>) prefs.getAll();
int n1 = prefCopy.getInt("num1", -1);
int n2 = prefCopy.getInt("num2", -1);
...
int n10 = prefCopy.getInt("num10", -1);
```

Comment: you might be able to save some milliseconds while giving up on getting updated values(from other parts) with additional hashmap memory. don't forget, preference should contain few values.